# How to create two-dimensional column chart in Microsoft Excel for Office 365

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I would like to create a two-dimensional column chart in Excel. On the x-axis I would like to plot % of Net Sales, and on the y-axis I would like to plot Gross Margin %. Here's an example:

[image: example]

You can see on the x-axis, percentage of Net Sales for the top 10 customers is just over 25%, and the gross margin on those ten customers is just under 30%. Net sales for the next 20 customers compose about 15% and the gross margin on those sales are around 26%

Here is my data:

```
Customer segment          Revenue   %of Net Sales   Gross Margin %
Customers 1-10          6.96 mill           20.7%            37.1%
Customers 11-30         5.68 mill           16.9%            42.2%
Customers, remaining   20.98 mill           62.4%            47.5%
```

Comment: Select the data, then `Insert -> Charts` then pick the kind of chart you want. For more details, see [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-chart-from-start-to-finish-0baf399e-dd61-4e18-8a73-b3fd5d5680c2)

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad the problem as I see it, is the OP wants to vary the width of the bars and have them stack to a total of  100 percent.  Last I checked excel bar graphs did not do that.  Or at least its not a straight forward option

Comment: Woah! totally did not see that (and I guess I'm not alone since someone upvoted my comment) What a non-intuitive chart layout. I know of know way to automatically get that from Excel.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad convoluted option I posted below but I think it works...your thoughts?

Comment: @Forward Ed - you, sir, are totally insane in the best possible way. I would just have done a couple of bar charts and redrawn the whole thing in Illustrator. This answer gets one upvote from me for thinking out of the box.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad agreed that other software would be better suited for the task.  However OP's opening line stated they wanted to use Excel.  Alternatively you could just put some random point in to get the graph axis and grid in and then manually draw a box in.

Comment: There is no built-in way to get this in Excel. But please see my tutorial [Variable Width Column Charts (Cascade Charts)](https://peltiertech.com/variable-width-column-charts/). It shows how to use area charts and a little axis trickery to get what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bar Charts in Excel do not vary their width as you are illustrating in your graph to the best of my knowledge.  The best I can do and its labour intensive is to outline the bars using an X-Y line scatter plot.  you have to create all the points of your bar and then plot them.  In my example I plotted them as a single series so it all the same colour, but you could plat it as individual series to get different colour or line pattern to the bar out line.  Unfortunately I do not know of a way fill in the bar.  (you could technically do it with a bunch of side by side lines).

my approximate solution created the points of interest in column E and F.  E being your X axis and F being your Y axis.  E is a running total based on your values from column C.
F is your Y value starting at 0 for the axis and the your value from D going across repeating and then back down to zero.  This results in the graph on the left below.  You can add text to your graph using text boxes.

For separate series to get different line colour the same process was followed except I separated the information in to separate columns in H through O.  Technically speaking you could have done this all from the info in columns E and F but you would need to be more careful grabbing the information for the start and end of your series data.  Separate columns just makes for easier reading.

[image: POC]

And here is an example of filling in the column by drawing a line back and forth and only increasing the the Y value by 1/100 of the max column value until the top of the column was reached.  Play with the 1/100 increase to find something that suits your needs.  In addition I turned the point markers off.

[image: POC FILLIN]

The reason you want to play with the 1/100 height step is if you move the chart from being and part of the sheet to being a page on its own, the lines start to show their gap.

[image: POC GAP]

Comment: I thought I was good at Excel, but this is amazing. The person who sent me the screenshot in the example isn't that good at Excel, but it looks like it's from Excel.  Anyway, thanks for you reply. Very helpful.

Comment: @dan I am admittedly limited to version 2013.  There is a possibility that there is a bar chart option that will allow you to vary the widths across the base in new versions.

Comment: @Dan looking at your picture, I just noticed the edges of the bars.  They seem to be a 3D edge effect.  As such I am guess those are manually drawing n objects sitting on top of the graph.

Comment: @ScottCraner is this a possible bar chart option in 2016?

Comment: Across my company, I'm pretty sure most of us are using version 2016. On my machine, I am using Microsoft Excel for Office 365. I tried a bunch of chart options, and none of them allow to vary column width. The best I could get is using a scatterplot, but it doesn't fill in easily. The person who sent me this isn't that great at Excel, so it leads me to believe the chart has to be automatic in some way. There's a possibility, they were using PowerBI, but I'm not that well-versed in BI and don't know for sure.

Comment: This is not possible in Excel with standard charts. But I have a tutorial that shows how to get this effect with area charts: [Variable Width Column Charts (Cascade Charts)](https://peltiertech.com/variable-width-column-charts/).

Comment: @JonPeltier This is cool. This must be the way the chart in the screenshot was created. Thanks for this.